# request page by curl

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I wanna make process on `$url` address,so I use this code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

It will do it and return response to.

I don't need to get response of page,I think it will be faster and use less traffic.
is following code can do it?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_exec($ch);
```

`$url` is captcha maker url.

Comment: My favorite type of question: "Does this code work?". My response: Try it and see?

Comment: it's captcha maker url,how should I know it works?

Comment: Test your code. If it does what you want it to, then it worked. If it doesnt do what you wanted it to, then it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you omit

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

response will go directly to output, connection itself works the same way, so this will not save you neither time nor traffic. But you can set CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST to 'head', this way you will receive only headers of response (without html).

Comment: if I request only header,the captcha maker page,should render image too?

Comment: In theory. I don't know how that captcha generator is written.